# Use group by with sum in query

Tags: sql, sql-server

These 3 tables that you see in the image are related
Course table and coaching table and sales table
I want to make a report from this table on how much each coach has sold by each course period.

The query I created is as follows, but unfortunately it has a problem and I do not know where the problem is.
Please help me fix the problem
Thank you

```
SELECT        
dbo.tblCustomersOrders.id, dbo.tblCustomersOrders.pid, dbo.tblPost.postTitle, 
dbo.tblArticleAuthor.authorName, SUM(dbo.tblCustomersOrders.prodPrice) AS TotalBuys
FROM            
dbo.tblPost 
INNER JOIN
    dbo.tblArticleAuthor ON dbo.tblPost.id = dbo.tblArticleAuthor.articleID 
INNER JOIN
    dbo.tblCustomersOrders ON dbo.tblPost.id = dbo.tblCustomersOrders.pid
GROUP BY dbo.tblCustomersOrders.pid
```

[image]

Comment: You typically GROUP BY the same columns as you SELECT, except those who are arguments to set function. I.e. try `GROUP BY dbo.tblCustomersOrders.id, dbo.tblCustomersOrders.pid, dbo.tblPost.postTitle, 
dbo.tblArticleAuthor.authorName`.

Comment: Tip of today: Table aliases!!! Spare some typing, make code easier to read, use table aliases! Like `FROM            
dbo.tblPost p`, then you can do `p.postTitle` instead of `dbo.tblPost.postTitle`.

Comment: Where is the Course table? Which column is the course period?

Comment: The course table is a subset of the post table that does not need to be in this query

Comment: Help us help you - share some sample data and the result you'd like to get for it

Comment: For example, from course number 1, which is sold 5 times by coach number 6, I want to get the total sales amounts of number 6 from course number 1.

Comment: @jarlh I think it is just "raw" SSMS-generated code, that's why "it iiiis what it iiiis".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this use, [SUM()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/sum-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) is an Aggregate Function, so you need to refer all the
fields that you want to get in your result set.

Example:

```
SELECT       
  dbo.tblCustomersOrders.id, dbo.tblCustomersOrders.pid, dbo.tblPost.postTitle, 
  dbo.tblArticleAuthor.authorName, SUM(dbo.tblCustomersOrders.prodPrice) AS TotalBuys
  FROM dbo.tblPost 
  INNER JOIN
       dbo.tblArticleAuthor ON dbo.tblPost.id = dbo.tblArticleAuthor.articleID 
  INNER JOIN
       dbo.tblCustomersOrders ON dbo.tblPost.id = dbo.tblCustomersOrders.pid
  GROUP BY dbo.tblCustomersOrders.id, dbo.tblCustomersOrders.pid, 
  dbo.tblPost.postTitle, dbo.tblArticleAuthor.authorName
```

But this query does not solve the need for your report.
If you just need to get "how much each coach has sold by each course" , you can try the query bellow.

```
SELECT        
 dbo.tblArticleAuthor.authorName, dbo.tblPost.postTitle, 
 SUM(dbo.tblCustomersOrders.prodPrice) AS TotalBuys
 FROM dbo.tblPost 
 INNER JOIN
    dbo.tblArticleAuthor ON dbo.tblPost.id = dbo.tblArticleAuthor.articleID 
 INNER JOIN
    dbo.tblCustomersOrders ON dbo.tblPost.id = dbo.tblCustomersOrders.pid
 GROUP BY dbo.tblArticleAuthor.authorName, dbo.tblPost.postTitle
```

If you need, send more details regarding the desired result.

Here you can find more information about SQL SERVER Aggregate Functions:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/aggregate-functions-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15

And here a quick example regarding SQL Aliases to build queries with a simple
and effective way:

https://www.w3schools.com/sql/trysql.asp?filename=trysql_select_alias_table

Answer (score 0):

Per your description of the task, the problem is that you only GROUPed BY dbo.tblCustomersOrders.pid, which is the period's id I guess, but you also need to GROUP BY the coach, which is dbo.tblArticleAuthor.authorName, I guess again. Plus in the SELECT field list you can not use more columns only that are aggregated + GROUPed.

Comment: See Suppose the post table is our courses and the author table is our instructors and the sales orders table is each of our courses
In this query, I want to know how much has been sold by each instructor from the courses that the instructors have put on the site

Comment: @NetProjectsIr What is it that you want to say? Did you try anything that I wrote?